# C++ - Windows - BIOS serial number - How to get

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to know BIOS serial number through C++ (Windows).

I tried `wmic bios get serialnumber` .

However, it shows no information.

Can anybody help me, how to get that.

Answer (score 1):

This info is in the registry, if it helps...

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\BIOS]
"BiosMajorRelease"=dword:00000004
"BiosMinorRelease"=dword:00000006
"ECFirmwareMajorRelease"=dword:000000ff
"ECFirmwareMinorRelease"=dword:000000ff
"BaseBoardManufacturer"="Dell Inc."
"BaseBoardProduct"="0YJPT1"
"BaseBoardVersion"="A00"
"BIOSReleaseDate"="03/21/2012"
"BIOSVendor"="Dell Inc."
"BIOSVersion"="A03"
"SystemFamily"="To be filled by O.E.M."
"SystemManufacturer"="Dell Inc."
"SystemProductName"="XPS 8500"
"SystemSKU"="To be filled by O.E.M."
"SystemVersion"=""
```

If the info you need is in there, it'll be a lot easier reading the registry than using wmi IMHO